# iOS 11 UINavigationBar Transparency in pushed ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11

I've been trying to implement Apple Music like transparent navigation bar for pushed view controller. There are a lot of solutions on Internet saying place the code below into viewDidLoad:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage =  UIImage()
```

But the thing is that it only works for root controller, e.g. UITableViewController with a list of items. When I tap on an item and open it's details I expect to see transparent navigation bar, but after appearing it becomes solid (not even translucent). Even setting barTintColor does not help.

What am i doing wrong? Or is it a known issue in iOS 11? It used to work before...

Answer (score 3):

I confirm that transparent navigation bar is not working in iOS 11 for pushed viewcontroller, instead just appears black without translucent @screenshot.

[image]

Firstly, I have filed this bug report, lastly :) I found a quick workaround that presenting and dismissing a UIViewcontroller fixes this issue, as following:

```
if (self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count > 1) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.present(UIViewController(), animated: true, completion: {
            self.dismiss(animated: false)
        })
        self.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    } else {
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    }
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
}
```

I am using above code in `viewWillAppear` and my UI is being generated programatically without storyboard or xib, so it works seamlessly :) and glad I get expected result @screenshot

[image]

Comment: Does not seem to work in my case, though thanks for your time. Still there must be a fix for it from Apple. I wonder how they preserved this behavior in Apple Music app. It is built with the latest sdk (as far as we see large titles), so they should have faced the same problem.

Comment: @SergeyPetrachkov my issue was in this line, 'parentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false', make sure you dont have `isTranslucent = false` on parent viewcontroller